# Flutter - after save add command in terminal

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am programming in Flutter but as a viewer I am using the web browser (not Android console or custom) below I leave the image
[image: imagen1]

Ok, so to compile each change you press `CTRL + S` and then I must go to the terminal and press the `R` key to be able to refresh the changes
[image: imagen2]

but this in development takes time away from me because I have to go to the end to press the `R` for each change.

Is there a way that pressing `CTR + S` and automatically hits the `R` key in terminal?

Comment: All i have to do is press `CTR + f5` and everything is taken care off. I don't need to press anything else

Comment: Strangely it worked, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it. Just press `CTRL + F5`, a new browser opens, then only by pressing `CTR + S` the changes will be updated.